# Django IF Statement for Session Values in View?

Tags: python, django

Not sure if this is the right approach, however I do have a view where I would like to use the `if` statement and compare model value with a session value.

I'm trying this:

**view.py**

```
r = MyModel.objects.get(id=id)
if r.mysize <= request.session['mysize']:
    #do this
else:
    #do something else
```

Both values do exist but for some reason I just can validate them.

it works if I use a number:

```
if r.mysize <= 10:
```

but it doesn't work with the session value.

I also tried this  but that didn't work either.

```
sessionsize = request.session['mysize'] 
if r.mysize <= sessionsize
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the actual value of `request.session['mysize'] `?

Comment: Its a number. (or should be a number). The value is set based on user selection from a form on previous page and is set in another view as `request.session['mysize'] = request.POST['mysize']`. I can see the values correctly displayed with `request.SESSION.mysize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you store request.POST data, it's not an integer but a string
try to coerce to int:

```
try:
     if r.mysize <= int(request.session['mysize']): 
       #do this
     else:
       #do else
except ValueError:
     # do else ?
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Provided  it is set correctly into session, you can try to convert to int:

```
if r.mysize <= int(request.session['mysize'])
```